# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Purchases' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

выдаёт такую ошибку: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Purchases' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
что делать ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MvcPhone.Models;

namespace Shop.Models.Order
{
    public interface IPhoneRepository
    {
        IEnumerable <Phone> GetAllPhones();
        Phone GetPhoneId(int phoneId);
        string Delete(int phoneId);
        string Create(Phone phone);
        string Update(string name,string producer, string shortdescription, int price, int id);
        string Buy(Purchase purchase);
    }
}



using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MvcPhone.Models;

namespace Shop.Models.Order
{
    public class MockPhoneRepository : IPhoneRepository
    {
       public string Buy(Purchase purchase)
       {
            var _buyDb = Db.Purchases;
            Db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
            Db.SaveChanges();

            return "yes";
        }
    }
}



namespace MvcPhone.Models
{
    public class Purchase 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}



namespace Shop.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
public ActionResult Buy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public string Buy(Purchase purchase)
        {
            _phoneRepository.Buy(purchase);

            return "Purchased";
        }
}
}


<form method="post" action=" ">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td><input asp-form = "Country" type = "text" name = "Country" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Producer</td>
                <td><input asp-form = "City" type = "text" name = "City" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2"><input type = "submit" value = "Add Address" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: *что делать ?* Не пытаться вставлять значение в поле-автоинкремент. Оно как-нить само присвоится.

Comment: Эм.. Я только вчера такой же вопрос читал...

Comment: Ага, нашёл его :)

Comment: помогите и мне найти

Comment: @Akina а как не присваивать поле-автоинкремент ?